# Build/compile Kubernetes for signature verification only and not signing

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a build/compile flag for kubernetes v1.14 to only build for signature verification and not signing? I have an embedded system acting as a kubelet that justs needs to verify a signature. I'm getting error saying, `kubelet[289]: remote_image.go:113] PullImage "quay.registry/reponame/podman-test:latest" from image service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Source image rejected: Invalid crypto engine` which indicates that kubernetes is missing external dependencies for signing.

I've tried adding:
`-tags "containers_image_openpgp "` similar to related issue here:
https://github.com/containers/skopeo/issues/660

My current build command is 
`make generated_files KUBE_BUILD_PLATFORMS="${HOST_GOOS}/${BUILD_GOARCH}"; make cross KUBE_BUILD_PLATFORMS=${GOOS}/${GOARCH}`

Comment: I use [rancher/k3s](https://github.com/rancher/k3s) in embedded os, which is more lightweight and easy to delpoy.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from GPG. Make sure your device has `gpg` or `gpgv` command in `PATH` and that [signature verification with gpg command](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html) works. 
`gpgv` is a stripped-down verification-only command that you could use, and Kubernetes supports it. Also, GPG has [a ton](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=configure.ac;h=0041bec526c69baff880d4964f6b4260d8c11318;hb=refs/heads/STABLE-BRANCH-2-0) of compile-time parameters to enable/disable parts of it, you can strip it down once you get it working. 
If you find GPG too bloated or have a hard time getting it to work, you can try using https://sequoia-pgp.org/ which compiles to a statically linked binary without external dependencies. You will have to translate calls to `gpg` command into calls to `sqv`, but their CLI interfaces are [really](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gpgv.1.html) [similar](https://docs.sequoia-pgp.org/0.8.0/sqv/) so it should be easy to do with a shell script, or whatever language your embedded platform supports.